# python flask-socketio TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: java, android, python, flask, flask-socketio

I started to use Socketio, and I got a problem. I can't send a simple message to my flask session. My Java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.8.101:8080/send");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

        }

    }

    public void TestButton(View v){
        Log.d("send","before send");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("message", "hi");
            obj.put("binary", new byte[42]);
            socket.emit("mes", obj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My Python code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@socketio.on("mes", namespace="/send")
def chat_message(message):
    print("message:")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start")
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' <Greenlet at 0x24118773178: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method WSGIServer.handle of <WSGIServer at , <bound method StreamServer.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed]  object, fd=-1, )> failed with TypeError
```

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem. I've searched everywhere and i can't find my answer.

Comment: When you post a Python error, please include the complete stack trace, as that provides additional information and context for the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use python3 with the gevent and gevent-websocket plugin.
gevent-websocket does not support python3 yet.

You have to options here:

1. Uninstall gevent and gevent-websocket and use eventlet.
2. Fix the code geventwebsocket/handler.py at line 236.

   ```
   if b'101' not in self.status:
   ```

I hope I could help you.